# How do I parse a date string in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

Suppose I have a string containing a date: `"11/10/2020"` (mm/dd/yyyy). Is there a way to parse this into a date data type in Racket? Scheme has [SRFI 19](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-19/srfi-19.html) (Time Data Types and Procedures) which defines `string->date` for parsing date strings. Is there something similar in Racket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something similar.  It's ... SRFI 19:

```
(require (only-in srfi/19 string->date))
(string->date "11/10/2020" "~m/~d/~Y")
```

I don't want to be rude, but searching in the Racket documentation for `string->date` would have found you this: it found me it when I needed to parse some dates & times.

Comment: yeah, when you know the name of the function it's easy to find by searching. otoh, if you're perhaps new to lispy languages then you'd probably never think to search for "string->date."

the documentation i have says "The date structure produced by this SRFI library is identical to the one provided by racket/base in most cases (see date)", but racket/date doesn't appear to have string->date, just date->string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `parse-date` where you provide the string and date pattern as arguments.
Here is the link to function...
[racket standard date parsing](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gregor/time-format.html#%28def._%28%28lib._gregor%2Fmain..rkt%29._parse-date%29%29)

Comment: The Gregor library is not part of the default Racket installation. It has to be installed using `raco pkg install gregor`.

Comment: True, it's not in the standard library, though it's a really popular package and it almost got into the standard library (see https://github.com/racket/racket/issues/1220)